# Why two device on the same router cannot communicate to each other

Tags: networking, router, lan, nas, ping

I am very new to networking and I don't know much about them so please make it simple for me. so right now I have two devices connected directly via Ethernet ( LAN 1 = Server and LAN 2 = PC ) to the same router, both of them can ping to router ( and also the router itself can ping to both of them) but they cant ping to each other. So I tried to connect both of device into my old router and both of them can ping each other very smoothly. so is there any setting i should change on my new router to open access between two LAN port on my router? My router is ztef609 and the old router that I used to test the connection is TP Link TD W8951ND. I don't know much about the new router configuration menu cause it seems pretty complex compare to my old router.

Comment: Try disabling IPv6 on both devices - server and PC.

Comment: It sounds like the router is in client isolation mode. Meaning it prevents client from talking to each other.

Comment: so in my router settings there are option  " enable isolation " and it is unchecked . I also uncheck " enable ssid isolation" too. is there any other form of isolation that i may have missed ?

Comment: i have tried to disable ipv6 on both device and i still get " Destination Host Unreachable" from both of device while trying to ping to each other